# by jquery, after row click handler return first td attribute in clicked row

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('#myTable tr:last');` i get a tr content(without `tr` tag). how can i get tr attribute? I can't. then tried to get attribute **er** from first `td` on clicked row. and now same problem.

```
$('#myTable tr').click(function() {
   var State = $(this).find("td:first-child").attr("er"); // this code is false
   alert(State);
});
```

**My HTML**

```
             <table width="600px" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ...
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ...
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ...
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ...
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ...
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    !
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#484848">
                    <td width="152px;" class="textField" er="editable">
                        <input type="text" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="350px;">
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select disabled="disabled">
                            //options
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td width="152px;">
                        <input type="text" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Need to see HTML for this to see what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me

```
$("#example tr:last").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("td:first"));
});

$("#example tr:last").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

First event prints the first td in the last tr on click on the last tr.

Second event prints the class attribute in the last tr on click on the last tr.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `$(this).find("td:first")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tr attribute by using `$(this).parent()`

Comment: if in my table row have attribute er I tried $(this).parent().attr("er");  but it does not work